# How do you add a const variable into document.cookie

Tags: javascript

I have the code below that works on a form, this previously submitted to a localstorage item and worked fine, but I now need to change it to store a cookie instead as it works better for how I'm trying to use the data.

Here is my code

```
let mycar = [];
const gen = document.getElementById('gen').value;
const addcar = (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    document.cookie = 'carGeneration='(gen)'; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2040 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
    location.reload();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addcar);
});
```

This will do part of what I'm after if I change carGeneration='(gen)' to carGeneration=S10 but I need this to populate the cookie based on the value submitted for const gen. Would anyone be able to help with this? I feel like it is likely simple but there aren't many examples of what I'm trying to do online. I'm thinking that the issue is likely with how I'm trying to add the const gen variable.

Would appreciate any help!

**Whoever closed my question, please read the question, it's not about getting the value from the cookie, it's about adding a const variable into the line to set the cookie.**

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

```
let mycar = [];
const addcar = (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    const gen = document.getElementById('gen').value;
    document.cookie = 'carGeneration='+gen+'; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2040 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addcar);
});
```